# Why is my JButton size not changing with either setSize() or setPreferredSize()?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, grid-layout, boxlayout

I am making a basic calculator for a school project, and one of the requirements I need to meet is to change the size of a JButton inside of a JPanel. I have tried to do this, but it doesn't change.

I have tried to use both `setSize()` and `setPreferredSize()` to change it, but neither of those methods work. I have also tried to set its size without adding it to the JPanels (explained in the code) and just adding it to the frame and that doesn't work either.

For online help, I have looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2536873/how-can-i-set-size-of-a-button/51019542#51019542) question here on Stack Overflow, and I (somewhat) copied it's code but it doesn't work.

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

## Code

### Imports

```java
import java.awt.GridLayout ;
import java.awt.Dimension ;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent ;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener ;
import javax.swing.JFrame ;
import javax.swing.JPanel ;
import javax.swing.JButton ;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout ;
```

### Class

```java
public class Main {
    public JFrame frame = new JFrame("Calculator") ;
    public JButton one = new JButton("1") ;
    public JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel() ;
    public JPanel buttonsPanel = new JPanel() ;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main main = new Main() ;

        main.one.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500)) ;

        main.one.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("Take that fat L") ;
            }
        }) ;


        main.buttonsPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 3)) ;
        main.buttonsPanel.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(2500, 1500)) ;
        main.buttonsPanel.add(main.one) ;
        main.mainPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(main.mainPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS)) ;
        main.mainPanel.add(main.buttonsPanel) ;

        main.frame.setContentPane(main.mainPanel) ;
        main.frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE) ;
        main.frame.setSize(500, 700) ;
        main.frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null) ;
        main.frame.setVisible(true) ;
    }
}
```

Comment: The layout manager `GridLayout` will already automatically scale the button you have placed inside the `buttonsPanel`. You don't need to use `setPreferredSize()`.

Comment: In general, you should avoid calling `setPreferred/Minimum/MaximumSize` and rely on layout properties and borders

Comment: I would start by getting rid of `main.frame.setSize(500, 700) ;` and replacing it with `main.frame.pack()`

Comment: Just so I'm making my point clear - the reason to avoid things like `setPreferredSize` is it overrides the components own internal functionality, so if your user has there font settings cranked up (like I often do), your layout will suffer because of it (ie - it won't be able to compensate)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Would it make sense to tell him what to do rather than what not to? Would margins, padding or borders be more appropriate? How much information does a beginner need for a first UI?

Comment: @queeg First, I like to inform the user of "why" an approach is wrong, maybe provide a bead crumb of ideas which help them solve there own problems, this will hopefully help them develop skills to further solve other issues in the future. Second, not every combination of settings will work for every problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The combination of `setPreferredSize`, `setMinimumSize` and `setSize` (on the window) are working against you.

I got rid of `buttonsPanel.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(2500, 1500));` and replaced `frame.setSize(500, 700)` with `frame.pack()` and this seems to have fixed the immediate problem.

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {
        public JButton one = new JButton("1");
        public JPanel buttonsPanel = new JPanel();

        public TestPane() {
            one.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));

            one.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    System.out.println("Take that fat L");
                }
            });

            buttonsPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 3));
            //buttonsPanel.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(2500, 1500));
            buttonsPanel.add(one);
            setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
            add(buttonsPanel);
        }
    }
}
```

However, this leaves you with another problem.  `setPreferredSize` is overriding the internal logic used by the button to calculate it's preferred size based on it's internal properties.

This might not seem like a big issue, but when you have users with unusual font settings, it quickly comes back to haunt you.

Swing has a good layout management system and you should spend some time trying to work out how to make use of it.

For example, if we start with something like...

```
public class TestPane extends JPanel {
    public TestPane() {
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.ipadx = 50;
        gbc.ipady = 50;
        int count = 0;
        for (int row = 0; row < 3; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < 3; col++) {
                JButton btn = new JButton(Integer.toString(++count));
                gbc.gridy = row;
                gbc.gridx = col;
                add(btn, gbc);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, this is making use of `GridBagLayout`, not the simplest of layouts, but defiantly one of the most flexible.  The reason for choosing it is it allows the possibility of applying an "internal" padding to the components, in this example, adding `50` to both the width and height.

This will generate something like...

[image]

Okay, big deal you say.  But consider what happens when the font size changes (in this example I manually modify the font size, but it could also come from system settings/preferences)

```
public class TestPane extends JPanel {
    public TestPane() {
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.ipadx = 50;
        gbc.ipady = 50;
        int count = 0;
        Font font = new JButton().getFont();
        font = font.deriveFont(font.getSize2D() * 12);
        for (int row = 0; row < 3; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < 3; col++) {
                JButton btn = new JButton(Integer.toString(++count));
                btn.setFont(font);
                gbc.gridy = row;
                gbc.gridx = col;

                add(btn, gbc);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Which outputs something like...

[image]

And, without any modification to the original code (other then adding in the font sizing), the code just works.

This is why we generally discourage the use of `setPreferred/Minimum/MaximumSize`

Now, if you "really" want square buttons, I recommend having a look at [Creating Square Buttons in Swing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16257125/creating-square-buttons-in-swing).  You could also try something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29023809/restarting-minesweeper-gui-program/29023997#29023997), but to be honestly, I prefer the first approach.

Comment: Thank you for sharing a good example together with explanations.